# Certificates, wallet creation and import certificate

Tags: keystore, weblogic-10.x, oim, oam

Generated new csr and CA signing has been done. Created new wallet using ora pki command.
Can anyone help me to understand what exactly to do get ohs acts as load balancer for SSL

Answer (score 0):

I can refer you to OHS server acting as a front-end to Oracle WebLogic Servers which is similar to acting as a Load balancer to to the WebLogic servers. FYI, this is for a use case from Oracle Fusion Middleware using a Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) as front for Oracle WebLogic Servers (WLS) with the use of mod_wl_ohs.
If you are already aware of mod_wl_ohs directive then proceed with the below link for "Configuring the mod_wl_ohs plug-in of OHS". If not then read up this directive or configuration called as "mod_wl_ohs" which you will use now. (typically you will be modifying a file called as mod_wl_ohs.conf in the OHS server). In summary mod_wl_ohs receives a request requiring a Managed Server (of the WebLogic cluster), it sends that request to one of the WebLogic cluster members listed in the directive of mod_wl_ohs. Next you will need to configure this mod_wl_ohs to use ssl. [Here is a good blog that provides steps for enabling ssl with mod_wl_ohs](https://middlewaretimes.blogspot.com/2014/03/configuring-modwlohs-to-use-ssl-between.html)

[Read Configuring the mod_wl_ohs plug-in for OHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e37889/oracle.htm#PLGWL510)
This chapter provides the steps to configure mod_wl_ohs. mod_wls_ohs is the plug-in for proxying requests from Oracle HTTP Server to Oracle WebLogic server. So what this means is that your OHS is front-ending the incoming requests, which then get forwarded to the WebLogic servers (or WebLogic cluster).
Note: The mod_wl_ohs module is included in the Oracle HTTP Server installation. You need not download and install it separately.